# How to tell the length a unit vector needs to be in order to pass another

Tags: math, 2d, linear-algebra, vector-graphics

Let's say I have two items: a unit direction vector, and another arbitrary vector.

What I want to get is the length to make the unit vector so that it covers the "distance" or magnitude of the other vector. So the new vector "contains" the other vector but maintains its direction.

Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: No, I don't see what you're saying. Do you mean that you want a vector with the direction of the unit vector and the magnitude of the arbitrary vector?

Comment: I'm unsure if you're trying to find the component of the arbitrary vector in the direction of the unit vector (use dot product)... or if you just want to multiple the unit direction by the absolute value of the arbitrary one.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by one vector containing another. I am aware of no standard definition for such a relationship among vectors.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase it in proper terms: Get a vector containing the direction of the unit vector but its component parallel to the other arbitrary vector is congruent to that arbitrary vector. Now? Sorry, I haven't really yet taken any vector-related math course, I've learned it all myself.

Comment: I recommend that you provide an example with two vectors, for example, if your unit vector is `(1/(sqrt 2), 1/(sqrt 2))`, and your other vector is `(4,3)` (length 5) what do you expect the "containing" extension of your unit vector to be?

Comment: All you need is a dot product.

Comment: I think it's more complex that you think but it does involve the dot product. I THINK he wants a vector (An).b/|b| = |b| where A is a length and n is the unit vector...

Comment: OK, I think I understand but don't know how to express this properly so the answer may not look to good... hang on a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (you want vector v):

You want a vector v = (An) where:

```
(An).b = |b|
```

Here A is just a number, n is the unit vector and b is the arbitrary vector.

What this means is you want a vector with length A, but if you were to rotate the world so that b was on the x axis, the x component of (An) would be |b| (absolute value of b)

Therefore, in components:

```
A(n1b1 + n2b2 + n3b3) = sqrt(b1^2 + b2^2 + b3^2)
```

where n1 means the 1st (x) component of the vector n.

Therefore just re-arrange:

```
A = sqrt(b1^2 + b2^2 + b3^2)/(n1b1 + n2b2 + n3b3)
A = |b|/(n.b)
```

So the vector that you're are looking for is:
    v = A*n = n * |b|/(n.b)

I believe that's what you want.

Edit: I broke that into components when I REALLY didn't need to. Components are useful if you don't understand what all the terms mean though. But here's it in just vector maths:

```
An.b = A(n.b) = |b| = abs(b)
A = |b|/(n.b)
Therefore v = An = n * |b|/(n.b)
```